# Wps office opens for a few seconds and closes without warning or errors

Tags: wps-office

I am currently using Ubuntu 19.04 and after installing wps-office,whenever I try to open it, it opens and closes without warning/errors.

Edit: I tried opening from terminal, and I got the following error message

```
wps-office.et
Warning: Qt4 does not support Wayland!

(process:8011): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.

** (et:8011): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: An 
AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this 
recipient; type="method_call", sender="(null)" (inactive) 
interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="Hello" error name="(unset)" 
requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols 
specified are supported
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: 
collate_byname<char>::collate_byname failed to construct for 
/snap/wps-office/1/usr/bin/et: line 38:  8011 Aborted                 
(core dumped) "$SNAP/bin/desktop-launch" 
${gInstallPath}/office6/${gApp} ${gOptExt} ${gOpt} "$@"
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I installed using the Ubuntu Software GUI application.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't support Wayland.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia switching to X11 still doesn't work